# Como puedo meter el valor de esta session php

Tags: php

Hola amigos tengo esta mi variable en la segunda condicion se la quiero meter al `where` como lo hago.

```
f ($_SESSION['idusuario']==1) {

        $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(MontoAcumulado),0) as total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
    else{


    $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE Idproveedor = aqui quiero ponerle el varlo de la variable";
          return ejecutarConsulta($sql);    

    }
```

---

Este es mi código completo:

```
<?php 
//incluir la conexion de base de datos

session_start();

require "../config/Conexion.php";

class Consultas{



    //implementamos nuestro constructor
public function __construct(){

}

public function totalacumulado(){

    if ($_SESSION['idusuario']==1) {

        $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(MontoAcumulado),0) as total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
    else{


    $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra 
FROM acumuladocomisiones 
WHERE Idproveedor =$_SESSION['idusuario']";
          return ejecutarConsulta($sql);    


}


}
}


 ?>
```

---

Me esta tirando error de sintaxis aquí:

```
$_SESSION['idusuario']
```

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada debes de tener las variables de sesión inicializadas. Tanto para guardarlas como para obtenerlas.

```
session_start();

$sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra 
FROM acumuladocomisiones 
WHERE Idproveedor = $_SESSION['idusuario']";

return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
```

Comment: Se me fue el dedo disculpa.